# How do I get specific information about the Arm CPU in a Windows UWP app?

Tags: uwp, arm, cpu

I want to know the exact name of the cpu. (Windows UWP App)

For example)
Qualcomm Snapdragon 810 2GHz or 
Qualcomm Snapdragon 800 2.2GHz etc.

I tried the following.

```
 var asyncOp = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(@"System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=""{97FADB10-4E33-40AE-359C-BEF029DBDD0}""");

 while (asyncOp.Status == AsyncStatus.Started)
     CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption.ProcessAllIfPresent);

 if (asyncOp.Status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
 {
     var info = asyncOp.GetResults()
     .....
 }
```

However, the above code shows the x86 cpu to the exact name and even the clock, but the Arm cpu does not.

Arm cpu returns only the following strings:
ACPI \ Qualcomm_Inc *-* ARM_Family_7_Model_D03_Revision ___ 2 \ 1

Anyway, I want to get an exact name for the arm, just like for x86 cpu.

Thanks advance.

Comment: Not sure what's the desired arm cpu name you expected. 
"ACPI \ Qualcomm_Inc - ARM_Family_7_Model_D03_Revision ___ 2 \ 1“ already contains lots of information. Can you give a cpu name pattern as an example?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such API in UWP. I'd think you can use a database to store these information, and then retrieve the corresponding one according to the string you've got or your device model.